# Theme messed up after WP udpate

Tags: css, wordpress

My WordPress theme looks messed up after the engine upgrade for some reason, posts were displayed under each other in the past, but after the upgrade, they are making weird space below.

This is the main div CSS code:

```
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
```

and this is the CSS of the element itself:

```
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 260px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 31%);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 31%);
```

I have tried using line-height: 1 as well as vertical-align: top, but nothing seems to fix the issue, unfortunately.

Did anyone had the same issue? just in case this is the front page of my site that has a messed-up structure https://emilysquotes.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a incompatibility with jQuery, try installing the plugin called `Enable jQuery Migrate Helper` [Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/). this is however a temporary solution. your theme needs an update to fully resolve the issue

[image]